How can I use BigQuery in Short query optimized mode for Python google.cloud client?
I just found out about BigQuery short query optimized mode support. But can only find it on cloud console ?
How can I use it with python client
Couldn't find it on web
This features seems to deliver faster query response for shorter queries. I need this as I am using it for a RAG and I need to optimize the query generated by SQL generator


Hi @Mayukh Pankaj, Could you please check if the following documentation is helpful?

To run a query using short query optimized mode with python client, select the python option of the following documentation.  The current available version is  3.21.0 and up. Requires setting QUERY_PREVIEW_ENABLED=true environment variable.

Hi @Nithish, is there any Async version of this ?
How can I set the environment variable, and where to pass it ??
